# Automatic Borrowing in Function Signatures

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'd like to understand, what is the correct way to write function signatures that do not need moved values, and are happy to accept a borrowed value. Consider:

```
fn calculate(x:&f32) -> bool {
    if x > 5.0 {
        true
    }
    false
}
```

Given that I don't consume the value, the borrowed value is good enough for me in this function.

Now when I call this function, the situation varies, either that is the terminal place for the x value to end up in:

```
let x = 4.0;
calculate(&x);
```

Or I need to use x again afterwards.

```
let x = 4.0;
calculate(&x);
let y = x + 5.0;
```

While the above approach works, it's a bit fiddly for the user of the `calculate` function to have to keep putting ampersands in, especially in cases like this where the number is hard-coded:

```
calculate(&-2.5);
```

Just looks absurd - I'm telling the computer to create a value, borrow it, use it, then dispose of it.

I'd expect that for sized types like floats there'd be a way to simplify this. I do understand that for dynamically sized values there might be further complications.

Ideally I'd like to be able to call the function and pass it either a borrowed value or an owned value.

What is the right way of putting this function signature together? Is there a way to accept both f32 and &f32?

Edit:
Additionally, the other situation I have is this:

```
let x_borrowed = &4.0;
calculate(x_borrowed);
```

As in, I only have the borrowed value.

From the comments made so far, it seems like the calculate function should instead accept an `f32`. And when calling it, I should give it either `f32` or dereference an `&f32`. Unless there's an automatic dereferencing feature that someone can point me to?

Comment: When you're working with `Copy` types, there's usually no need for borrowing (unless that's something large like `[u32; 1000]`). Do you have any more specific reason to avoid owned arguments?

Comment: For types like numbers…see also [copy types](https://dhghomon.github.io/easy_rust/Chapter_19.html).

Comment: To answer your comments, I'm working with a lot of `f32`s that are inside `Vec<>` etc. and iterating through those usually yields `&f32`. I then need to call functions that take in these `&f32`s.

Comment: You can just deref the f32 when you are looping to make a copy `for i in v.iter() {my_fn(*i);}`

Comment: Rust implements implicit coercion for implicit transformation of &String to &str: https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch04-03-slices.html (read String Slices as Parameters there). For your own types, you can implement Deref (https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods), but that's not possible for something is defined outside your crate, such as f32.

Comment: @pigeonhands, yes that's what I seem to end up doing. The choice for me was either ampersands in one part of the code or asteresks in another part of the code. I was trying to make it all look a bit cleaner, given that in theory the function should work just fine whether you give it a reference or an owned value. But I guess the design of Rust is such that this needs to be shown explicitly. It would be nice if I could do `my_fn(i)` and it automatically dereferences, but there doesn't appear to be such a feature.

Comment: It will auto-deref on a method, so you could create a trait and implement a method to do it. Otherwise `AsRef` or `Into` are the other options.

Answer (score 2):

For types that implement the [Copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait, there is no need to pass a reference as the function will not take ownership of the original value, instead creating a copy to be passed into the function.

However, with types that do not implement `Copy` (such as `String`), you can use the [AsRef](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait for things like this.

```rust
fn is_length_of_4(s: impl AsRef<str>) -> bool {
    s.as_ref().len() == 4
}

// These will all work
assert!(is_length_of_4("Test"));
assert!(is_length_of_4(String::from("Test")));
assert!(is_length_of_4(&String::from("Test")));
```